# Как правильно сверстать в Android?

Tags: android, xml

Всем привет. Есть вот такой вот шаблон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размеры шаблона: Ширина 360 высота 640.

Так вот, фон градиента я сделал, но вот как правильно сверстать кнопки, чтобы они были показаны для разных устройств одинаково.

Как я начал делать:

1. Создал 2 горизонтальных `linear layout`
2. Вставил туда две кнопки
3. Выставил ширину и высоту кнопки как у картинки
4. И поставил фот кнопки как картинку

Как правильно сверстать данный шаблон?

Comment: TableLayout, либо GridLayout. Как сделать крестик посередине я не знаю :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, я думаю, лучше использовать TableLayout с двумя TableRow:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
</TableRow>
```

Получится вот так:

Портретная ориентация
[image: портретная ориентация]

Ландшафтная ориентация
[image: ландшафтная ориентация]

Comment: мне не нужно явно указывать размер кнопки?? он автоматически будет расширяться ужиматься при разных расширениях?

Comment: да, размер автоматически будет подгоняться под экран